# redis-cluster in kubernetes container restarts on spinup

Tags: kubernetes, redis, bitnami, rancher, redis-cluster

I am using bitnami redis-clusters' helm charts (slightly abridged) to deploy a 3 master 3 slave configuration to our k8s cluster. Every time I upgrade the deployment, of my 6 pods, on average at least 1 or 2 have 1-2 container restarts before they start up correctly. While they do eventually startup, it is nonetheless quite concerning that one day during a critical deploy they may not. As far as I can tell, this happens due to the {service}-redis-{i}.{service}-redis-headless DNS not resolving sometimes for some headless services. In particular, the following method does not consistently return the same information:

```
dns_lookup() {
    local host="${1:?host is missing}"
    getent ahosts "$host" | awk '/STREAM/ {print $1 }'
}
```

(From here: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-cluster/blob/master/5.0/debian-10/prebuildfs/opt/bitnami/scripts/libnet.sh#L19)

Sometimes, this returns the correct IP address (which means it will get past wait_for_dns_lookup), and other times it returns nothing.

Is there a way to guarantee the headless services exist and resolve properly for all nodes before I startup? Is there a known issue/resolution?

For context, we are running kubernetes with rancher, kubectl version produces the following:

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.6", GitCommit:"7015f71e75f670eb9e7ebd4b5749639d42e20079", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-11-13T11:11:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: Hi, Bitnami developer here. This is strange, as the headless service has the publishNotReadyAddress option set to true, so the pod should be resolvable. Could you provide more details about your Kubernetes environment? I'm not sure if it has to do with the DNS resolver you have in the cluster.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I added more details in an edit. Let me know what other info you would need. Also, I did validate that I did not remove the publishNotReadyAddress option

Comment: @JavierSalmeron The most interesting thing I've found, is that the dns_lookup succeeds *sometimes*. In fact, I added something that ran that method 5 times in a row, and sometimes it gave the desired result sometimes it didn't. What actually fails is that the empty value (when it fails) is not able to be set to a variable.

Comment: Is it something that I can reproduce at any moment? I mean, if I go to a pod and try the function, would it return empty values sometimes?

Comment: As far as I can tell it is only during initialization. I would have to double check however

Comment: Were you able to double check?